# Gradient descent for linear regression outputs all converge near (0, 0)

Tags: python, linear-regression, gradient-descent

I have been trying to implement my own gradient descent algorithm in Python and have been unable to get an output that suitably fits the data.

```py
class GradientDescent:
  def __init__(self,
               feature_data: list[float],
               response_data: list[float],
               initial_vector: list[float, float],
               learning_rate: float=0.001,
               iterations: int=20) -> None:
    '''
    Initialise GradientDescent class.

    Args:
      feature_data (list[float]): A list of feature values for each data point.
      response_data (list[float]): A list of actual response values for each data point.
      initial_vector (list[float, float]): The initial starting point for the gradient descent. Vector is gradient and y-intercept.
      learning_rate (float): Factor determining how much to adjust the vector.
      iterations (int): Number of times to run the gradient descent algorithm.
    '''
    self.feature_data = feature_data
    self.response_data = response_data
    self.initial_vector = initial_vector
    self.learning_rate = learning_rate
    self.iterations = iterations

  def _partial_difference_quotient(self,
                                   vector: list[float, float],
                                   index: int,
                                   small_change: float=0.0001):
    '''
    Calculate the partial difference quotient for a specific element of the vector.

    Args:
      vector (list[float, float]): The current vector representing model parameters.
      index (int): The index of the element in the vector for which to calculate the difference quotient.
      small_change (float): The small change applied to the specified element for estimating the gradient.
    Returns:
      float: The calculated partial difference quotient.
    '''
    modified_vector = vector.copy()
    modified_vector[index] += small_change
    return (self._cost(modified_vector) - self._cost(vector)) / small_change

  def _estimate_gradient(self, vector):
    '''
    Estimate the gradient of the cost function at a given vector.

    Args:
      vector (list[float, float]): The current vector representing model parameters.
    Returns:
      list[float]: A list of gradient estimates for each element of the vector.
    '''
    gradient_estimates = []

    for i in range(len(vector)):
      gradient_estimates.append(self._partial_difference_quotient(vector, i))

    return gradient_estimates

  def _update_vector(self, vector: list[float, float]) -> list[float, float]:
    '''
    Update the vector using gradient descent.

    Args:
      vector (list[float, float]): The current vector representing model parameters.
    Returns:
      list[float, float]: The updated vector after applying gradient descent.
    '''
    direction = self._estimate_gradient(vector)

    for i in range(len(vector)):
        vector[i] -= self.learning_rate * direction[i]

    return vector

  def _cost(self, vector: list[float, float]) -> float:
    '''
    Calculate the cost (loss) of a linear regression model's predictions.

    This function computes the cost, also known as the mean squared error, of a linear regression model's
    predictions compared to the actual response values, given the model parameters and the corresponding
    features and response data.

    Args:
      vector (list[float, float]): A list representing the model parameters (gradient and y-intercept).
    Returns:
      float: The calculated cost (mean squared error) of the model's predictions.
    '''
    cost = 0

    for i, element in enumerate(self.response_data):
      error = element - vector[0] - vector[1] * self.feature_data[i]
      cost += error * error

    return cost / (2 * len(self.response_data))

  def compute_gradient_descent(self) -> tuple[float, list[float]]:
    '''
    Perform gradient descent to optimize the model parameters.

    Returns:
      tuple[float, list[float]]: A tuple containing the optimized vector of model parameters and a list of cost values during optimization.
    '''
    next_vector = self.initial_vector
    cost_values = [self._cost(next_vector)]

    for i in range(self.iterations):
      next_vector = self._update_vector(next_vector)
      cost_values.append(self._cost(next_vector))

    return next_vector, cost_values
```

To test the code, I randomly choose starting vectors to try and minimise the chance of landing in a local minima:

```py
def main(runs: int=50, **kwargs: dict[str, float | int]) -> None:
  # Unpack keyword arguments
  learning_rate = kwargs.get("learning_rate", 0.0001)
  iterations = kwargs.get("iterations", 50)

  # Initialise lowest cost value at high value
  lowest_cost_value = 1_000_000

  # Perform gradient descent for each starting vector and draw the output line on the plot
  for i in range(runs):
    starting_vector = [randint(0, 1500)/100, randint(0, 1500)/100]
    gradient_descent = GradientDescent(
        feature_data=data["Exam Score"],
        response_data=data["Study Hours"],
        initial_vector=starting_vector.copy(),
        learning_rate=learning_rate,
        iterations=iterations
    )
    latest_vector, cost_values = gradient_descent.compute_gradient_descent()    

    if min(cost_values) < lowest_cost_value:
      lowest_cost_value = min(cost_values)
      lowest_cost_vector = latest_vector
      lowest_cost_starting_vector = starting_vector
      print(f"Lowest Cost: Value={lowest_cost_value}, Vector={lowest_cost_vector}, Starting Vector={lowest_cost_starting_vector}, Color={line_colors[i % len(line_colors)]}")
```

**Output:**

```
Lowest Cost: Value=1.3919698325898155, Vector=[0.3304394780995701, 0.07838640040339392], Starting Vector=[0.36, 1.92]
```

I plotted the results of each run and it doesn't seem correct (the bold red line is my manual estimation of the correct output, whilst the bold black line at the bottom is the algorithms best attempt with the lowest cost):
[image: 50 runs results]
Yet the cost function seems okay, with the best cost being 1.39 and the worst being 16.23:
[image: Cost function results]

Is there a particular reason that all the outputs seem to converge close to (0, 0) at (0.015, 0.084)? None of the solutions the algorithm outputted were representative of the data and it appears as though a HIGHER cost value yields a more accurate gradient so I'm really unsure what I am doing wrong here.

My expectations are that the output from the starting vector which yielded the lowest cost value would be the most accurate and fit the data the best. However, none of the algorithm's outputs seem to fit the data accurately at all, having a range of gradients but incorrect y-intercepts.

I've tried adjusting the learning rate and randomising the initial vectors as well as selecting initial vectors manually. I've seen about normalising the data but I'm unsure whether that is necessary as the range of values is simply 1-100 for Exam Scores and 1-10 for Study Hours.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Only had a quick glance at the code, nothing looked immediately wrong with the algorithmic part. But your learning rate and iterations counts are both pretty small, making it unlikely to "make it all the way" to the best result.  Try 1) testing this using artificial data that you generate from a known function (no noise), 2) initializing close to the known parameters, 3) far from the known parameters

Comment: Tip for when data you're plotting spans many orders of magnitude: use a log scale on that axis.

Answer (score 1):

I was set in the right direction by [@bogovicj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11928160/bogovicj)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77267837/gradient-descent-for-linear-regression-outputs-all-converge-near-0-0#comment136221541_77267837):

> Only had a quick glance at the code, nothing looked immediately wrong with the algorithmic part. But your learning rate and iterations counts are both pretty small, making it unlikely to "make it all the way" to the best result. Try 1) testing this using artificial data that you generate from a known function (no noise), 2) initializing close to the known parameters, 3) far from the known parameters

After testing the algorithm on a simple `y = x + 2` equation and finding the same issue, I (eventually) realised I had unintentionally swapped the gradient and y-intercept in the `_cost` function.

The correct solution swaps the indices when calculating the error to:

```py
error = element - vector[1] - vector[0] * self.feature_data[i]
```

This allowed the algorithm to work as intended and correctly matched the output of Scikit's LinearRegression implementation.

[image: My model versus Scikit model]